# The given path's format is not supported error with File.copy() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

When i try to copy the file from local machine to other machine within the local network, through file.copy() method in c#, i am encountered with the error saying, The given path's format is not supported

I am using the following syntax

```
File.Copy(@"C:\temp\sample.txt", @"\\DEMO-PC\D:\DummyFolder\sample.txt", true);
```

Comment: If you type \\DEMO-PC\D:\DummyFolder\ into Windows Explorer does it work? If not does it work with \\DEMO-PC\D$\DummyFolder\?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing the colon with a dollar sign:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\temp\sample.txt", @"\\DEMO-PC\D$\DummyFolder\sample.txt", true);
```

**EDIT**

The ':' character has a special status in Windows paths; it's not legal to use it in the name of a file share.  The '$' character also has a special status: it is used to designate hidden shares.  Windows automatically creates hidden file shares for each drive on a computer; omitting the colon because it's not legal, and adding the '$' to hide the share.

See this knowledge base article for more information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984

Comment: Thanks phoog that worked for me, can i know what is difference in adding $ instead of colon?

Comment: @mahesh You are welcome.  I have edited the answer to add some more information.